# Query nested documents on ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery

My nested_filter dont work, even my nested query.
I'have create a mapping like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/i_part' -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "part2": {
      "properties": {
         "p_name": {
             "type":   "string", "index":  "not_analyzed"
        },
        "lineorder": {
          "type": "nested",
           "properties": {
                "lo_quantity": {"type":"integer"},
                "lo_discount": {"type":"integer"}, 
                "lo_shippriority": {"type":   "string", "index":  "not_analyzed"},
                "lo_shipmode": {"type":   "string", "index":  "not_analyzed"},
                "customer"{
                    "properties":{
                      "c_name": {"type":   "string", "index":  "not_analyzed"}
                        }
                 }
            }
}
}
}
}
}
```

But when I query it the way under it returns all document.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/i_part/part2/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "nested" : {
          "path" : "lineorder",
          "filter": {
              "and": [
                {
                  "match" : {
                    "lineorder.lo_shipmode":"RAIL|"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match" : {
                    "lineorder.lo_orderpriority":"1-URGENT"
                  }
                }
              ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },       
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "p_partkey": 1 }}, 
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "lineorder", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ 
                  {"match": {"lineorder.lo_shipmode":"RAIL|"}},
                  {"match" : {"lineorder.lo_orderpriority":"1-URGENT"}}
                ]
        }}}}
      ]
}}
}'
```

or this way

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/i_part/part2/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "nested": { 
      "path": "lineorder",
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "lineorder.lo_discount": {
            "gte": 2,
            "lt": 4
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "lineorder.lo_discount": { 
      "order": "asc",     
      "nested_filter": { 
        "range": {
          "lineorder.lo_discount": {
            "gte": 2,
            "lt": 4
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

What I'm doing wrong? I would like to query nested fields not parent/child, because my data is too big to link the child to parent.

My data is something like this:

```
{
    "p_name": "lace spring",
    "lineorder": [{
                "customer": [{
                    "c_name": "Customer#000014704",
                }],
                "lo_quantity": 49,
                "lo_orderpriority": "1-URGENT",
                "lo_discount": 3,
                "lo_shipmode": "RAIL|",
                "lo_tax": 0
            }, {
                "customer": [{
                    "c_name": "Customer#000026548",
                }],
                "lo_quantity": 15,
                "lo_orderpriority": "3-MEDIUM",
                "lo_discount": 10,
                "lo_shipmode": "SHIP|",
                "lo_tax": 0
            }]}
```

Comment: Can you add an example document you expect this query to return?

Comment: In your first query you are using `match` on not analyzed fields. It won't work.

Comment: @DrTyrsa I have tried "term" too, but same problem.

Comment: @mbudnik, If you notice the lineorder has another nested array inside it, but I've not declared as nested. I've tried it with nested but doesn't work too. Both queries should return just the first lineorder.

Comment: @Raphael Do you want to filter `lineorder`s, not `part2`'s? Then you should use inner hits https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html

Comment: @DrTyrsa, thanks a lot, it works. Put it as a answer to give you some votes.

Comment: @Raphael yes, done

Comment: @DrTyrsa, its possible to aggregate inner hits? How can I show some parent data?

Comment: @Raphael Parent data should be returned with inner hits. What's your response? You can aggregate nested filelds ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html ), if you want to can add your filter to nested aggregation.

Comment: @DrTyrsa, I've found a solution for my problems here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415031/aggregation-on-filtered-nested-inner-hits-query-in-elasticsearch, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter `lineorder`s themselves you should use [inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html).